# Is there a jQuery selector to check if a tag has any attributes?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

In trying to select elements that have any attributes, the following throws a jQuery syntax error.

```
$("div[*]")
```

Is there a selector to check if a tag has any attributes?

Tested with jQuery 1.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went with Ariel Popovsky's suggestion to use filter, though if I needed this in many places, I would use petersendidit's suggestion of creating a customer selector.

The (important) difference is that the .specified property needs to be checked. IE always returns more than 80 attributes.

Note: even this is not 100%. There are some attributes, like INPUT .value, that are special cases, but since I'm using a DIV, I can ignore them.

```
$("div").filter(function()
{ 
    for (var i = 0; i < this.attributes.length; i++)
    {
        var attr = this.attributes[i];
        if (attr.specified) 
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
})
```

Answer (score 6):

I don't think so but this should do the trick

```
$('*').filter(function(){return this.attributes.length;})
```

and the opposite:

```
$('*').filter(function(){return !this.attributes.length;})
```

Answer (score 5):

You could create your own selector for no attributes:

```
$.expr[':'].noAttrs = function( objNode  ){
    if (objNode.attributes.length) return( true );
    return( false );
}

$("div:noAttrs")
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `if($('.class').attr('*:attr').length > 0)`